# ReactJS not redirecting when authentication fails

Tags: reactjs, redirect

I have a base component which checks for authentication via API. My script works to the point where it won't show the UI if authentication fails, but it does not redirect like I am expecting it to.

```
class Base extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isAuth: false,
            isLoaded: false
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL+'/account/validate-session', {
            session_id: cookies.get('session_id'),
            account_id: cookies.get('account_id')
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            if(response.data.status === "OK"){
                this.setState({
                    isAuth: true,
                    isLoaded: true
                })
            }
        }.bind(this))
        .catch(function (error) {
            this.setState({
                isAuth: false,
                isLoaded: true
            })
        }.bind(this));
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.currentPage = [
            this.props.page
        ]
    }

    render() {
        let date = new Date().getFullYear();
            if(this.state.isLoaded) {
                return (
                    this.state.isAuth ?
                    <Layout className="layout">
                        <Header className="header">
                            <div className="logo" />
                            <div className="title">
                                {/*{this.props.title}*/}
                                Homepage
                            </div>
                            <Menu theme="dark" mode="horizontal" defaultSelectedKeys={this.currentPage} style={{ lineHeight: '64px', float: 'left', marginLeft: '300px'}}>
                                <Menu.Item key="/home">
                                    <Link className="nav-text" to="/home">Home</Link>
                                </Menu.Item>
                                <Menu.Item key="/upload">
                                    <Link className="nav-text" to="/upload">Upload</Link>
                                </Menu.Item>
                            </Menu>
                            <Menu theme="dark" mode="horizontal" defaultSelectedKeys={this.currentPage} style={{ lineHeight: '64px', float: 'right'}}>
                                <Menu.Item key="/logout">
                                    <Link className="nav-text" to="/logout">Logout</Link>
                                </Menu.Item>
                            </Menu>

                        </Header>

                        <Content style={{ padding: '0 50px' }}>
                            {/*<Breadcrumb style={{ margin: '12px 0' }}>
                                <Breadcrumb.Item>Home</Breadcrumb.Item>
                                <Breadcrumb.Item>{this.currentPage}</Breadcrumb.Item>
                            </Breadcrumb>*/}
                            <div style={{ padding: 24, background: '#fff' }}>
                                {this.props.children}
                            </div>
                        </Content>
                        <Footer style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                            Copyright {date} Company, Inc.
                        </Footer>

                    </Layout>
                    :
                     <Redirect to="/"/>
                );
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Router:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
      <Component {...props}/>
  )}/>
)

ReactDOM.render((
    <LocaleProvider locale={enUS}>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/home" component={Home} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/upload" component={Upload}/>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/logout" component={Logout}/>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/review/:uploadId" component={Review}/>
                <Route component={ NotFound } />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </LocaleProvider>
), document.getElementById('root'))

registerServiceWorker();
```

I can see the API call being made, I can see that it returns a 401 authentication failed. The UI shows a blank page but the redirect does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: is this component is global? where does it load? on which page? url? could it be, you are on homepage and you redirect to homepage?

Comment: @TzookBarNoy I am on not authenticated, attempt to hit a url /home which requires auth and it shows the url /home in the browser but nothing loads on the screen, it should go back to the root e.g. /

Comment: so lets try quick debug, just place <h1>NotLogged</h1> instead of Redirect. If u see that, we know we have a problem with <Redirect />

Comment: @TzookBarNoy Good idea - yes it shows Not Logged in the UI, so the redirect must be the issue. Thanks

Comment: Please make sure to share your solution here :) or ping if you more problems

Comment: @TzookBarNoy No solution yet, trying to find something that works

Comment: what is your router package you are using?

Comment: please type your full code here

Comment: @TzookBarNoy Added the routes to the main question.